# .htaccess - rewrite nonwww to www; php to html; http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am trying since some hours to to following:
- .www requests should be rewriten to non-www
- php should be rewriten to html
- http should be rewritten to https
- all redirects with code 301

I am using following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301] 

# php to html
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [R=301]


# http to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

But it wont work. If i remove the http to https rule, i get follow results:

www with .html redirects to non-www with .php on the end:

```
 :~$ curl -I http://www.mydomain.com/index.html
 Location: http://mydomain.com/index.**php**
```

www with .php redirects to www with .html on the end:

```
 :~$ curl -I http://www.mydomain.com/index.php
 Location: http://**www.**mydomain.com/index.html
```

non-www with php works, it get redirected to html, which is correctly:

```
 :~$ curl -I http://mydomain.com/index.php
 Location: http://mydomain.com/index.html
```

And with the http to https rule everything is messed up, because the domain get double inserted:

```
 :~$ curl -I http://mydomain.com:81/index.php
 Location: https://mydomain.com:81/http://mydomain.com:81/index.html
```

I understand the problem with the http to https rewrite, the url is double inserted because it got already rewritten. But what would be the correct htaccess rule to solve this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try. If I'm clear on what you want, I believe this will handle your requirements.

```
# www to non www and HTTPS if not
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule (.*) https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#rewrite files to html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hello, awsome, curl gives back the right URLs. But i am getting a 404 error.
I think it is because i have saved the files as php, do you have a solution for that too?
Edut: And one other thing: When i make curl http://mydomain.com/index.html it gets to https://mydomain.com/index.php and then it get rewritten to https://mydomain.com/index.html. Would it be possible to make this in one step, so there are not two 301 redirects?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the PHP files? Are the php files real files and you want to just display them as html?

Comment: Yes, that are real php files.

Comment: Are the php files linked in the code? Because if you want them to be be shown as .html you should be using .html in your links and let apache do the redirects internally which I can update the code to do. It should be done that way.

Comment: Yes, some php files include other php files and execute php code.
I can update my apache config, would be nice if you could update your code.
HTTPS redirect will be still made over htaccess, right?

Comment: Yes I understand what the php files do, what I mean is links on your site should be somefile.html instead of somefile.php so when someone clicks on it apache will rewrite it to somefile.php and run your code. Do you see what I mean? Is that what you need?

Comment: The links on the page are already .html. But i want, the there is no duplicated content and everything is only reachable via https://mydomain.com/file.html ; so no www, no php, only ssl.

Comment: Gotcha, give that a try.

Comment: That works perfect. Only one thing: It get first redirected to Location: https://example.com/index.php - is there a way to make it directly to .html?

Sorry for my much inquire

Comment: It does that because it's handling the https/www redirection then it handles the file. It will be seamless to your users and it's not noticeable in the browser. It's instantaneous  I recommend to not make them to complex so you can easily change your rules later without changing the whole thing.

Comment: True, only worried about SEO. I have done some research and some says that double redirection is no problem, other says it should be avoid.
What you think about it? But I *believe* now that this is only a myth and has no impact?

Comment: Redirects to https is common and so are pretty urls. That shouldn't impact your SEO because the first rule is using a 301 which would transfer most your page ranking. There shouldn't be any significant affect.